# React Native - is there a library for sign in with Apple ID?

Tags: ios, react-native, authentication, app-store, apple-id

Looking for a **react-native** library to login with **AppleID**

Comment: relevant: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-apple-authentication ?

Comment: @Cherniv that's it! thanks

Answer (score 11):

We've (React Native Firebase team) recently released a library for this here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication

It's a complete implementation, well typed and documented, compatible with Firebase Auth and does not require Expo.

Comment: thanks, which version of react native does it require?
without expo usage i hope)

Comment: RN 60+ and no expo

Comment: Hi and thanks as well, just a question about react-native-firebase version, my current project is using 5.5.5, do I have to upgrade to 6.x.x. in order to use react-native-apple-authentication?

Comment: @bra.Scene - we backported the Firebase Authentication change to the latest version of v5 as well

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SystangoTechnologies/react-native-apple-sign-in thats it:) But it is supportable from XCode 11 and iOS 13. Although you can install XCode 11 on Mac Mojave 10.14.14 and later. If you have RN < 0.60 it's unpossible to use it